# Clone one row and all its references in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

is there a way in SQL server to clone a row and all its references?

To be more clear, in my case there are these tables:

```
Document
- Id
- RevisionedDocumentId
```

and

```
Paragraph
- Id
- DocumentId
- RevisionedParagraphId
```

Each `Document` has many `Paragraphs`.

When I create a revision of a Document i must to clone the row of the `Document` and each related rows of `Paragraph` table, and each new `Paragraph`must have a reference to the previous `Paragraph`, same thing for the `Document`.

Now the problem is that in my case there are also many other tables involved, so clone one to one, and linking each row to the source row is very boring, exists some "more speed" way to do it?

Comment: Maybe just `join`?

Comment: Why? This sounds  a lot like a row_version where each time an `UPDATE` is executed, it's really an `INSERT` with a column of `inserted_datetime` or something so you can track the changes. But, you wouldn't replicate all the paragraph. They'd still reference the Document table and you'd be focusing on the `max(inserted_datetime)`. I don't see why you'd want to denormalize your data by introducing duplicates.

Comment: well, a user create a revision of a `Document`, and then he can edit it, so it will be different from the original `Document`

Comment: You can start with an `insert ... select ...` with an `output` clause to copy the `Document` row. (You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows, e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.) Output the original and new id's to a table variable or temporary table. Use those values to fix up the next set of copies, i.e. `Paragraphs`. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.